# Set value to a variable in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Background:**
I have a tabel called History. In this table i have 3 different columns that represents 3 different types of adresses (domestic adress, foreign adress and other adress). A record set from this tabel may contain values for one, more or none of these adress types. I am therefore trying to retrieve the adresstype and it's value by using a CASE statement and assigning the value to a variable.

**Question:**
I get no errors in my query but it returns nothing. What am i doing wrong?

```
DECLARE @vAdress AS VARCHAR(50)

SELECT H.FIRSTNAME, H.LASTNAME, @vAdress, C.COUNTRY
FROM History H
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY C
ON H.COUNTRYCODE = C.COUNTRYCODE
WHERE H.EMAILADRESS = 'johndoe.doe@test.com'
AND @vAdress = CASE
                   WHEN H.D_ADRESS IS NOT NULL THEN H.D_ADRESS
                   WHEN H.F_ADRESS IS NOT NULL THEN H.F_ADRESS
                   ELSE H.O_ADRESS       
               END
```

Comment: Have you assigned value for `@vAdress` yet? You should give us your sample data with the corresponding result.

Comment: You can't assign a value in a `WHERE` clause. Sample data and a desired output would go a long way toward clarifying your logic and what you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Not with the "SET" keyword, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not use a variable and do not use the case statement within the where clause. Try this:

```
SELECT H.FIRSTNAME, H.LASTNAME, CASE
                   WHEN H.D_ADRESS IS NOT NULL THEN H.D_ADRESS
                   WHEN H.F_ADRESS IS NOT NULL THEN H.F_ADRESS
                   ELSE H.O_ADRESS       
               END as vAdress, C.COUNTRY
FROM History H
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY C
ON H.COUNTRYCODE = C.COUNTRYCODE
WHERE H.EMAILADRESS = 'johndoe.doe@test.com'
```

Comment: This solves my problem. However i was hoping i could set the value to a variable as i will have to go through the same procedure more than once. I'm marking this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

With no sample data, this is impossible to say what's "wrong" apart from to say that the reason it's failing is because there's no rows that meet the criteria.

I would, however, write the above using boolean logic; perhaps that would give you the answer:

```
SELECT H.FIRSTNAME,
       H.LASTNAME,
       @vAdress,
       C.COUNTRY
FROM History H
     LEFT JOIN COUNTRY C ON H.COUNTRYCODE = C.COUNTRYCODE
WHERE H.EMAILADRESS = 'johndoe.doe@test.com'
  AND (H.D_ADRESS = @vAdress
   OR  (H.D_ADRESS IS NULL AND H.F_ADRESS = @vAdress)
   OR  (H.D_ADRESS IS NULL AND H.F_ADDRESS IS NULL AND H.O_ADRESS = @vAdress))
```

Of course, this ***assumes*** you've assigned a value to `@vAdress`. Nothing equals `NULL`, so if `@vAdress` is `NULL`, it'll never return any results.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE @vAdress AS VARCHAR(50)

SELECT H.FIRSTNAME, H.LASTNAME, @vAdress, C.COUNTRY
FROM History H
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY C
ON H.COUNTRYCODE = C.COUNTRYCODE
WHERE H.EMAILADRESS = 'johndoe.doe@test.com'
AND (CASE
        WHEN H.D_ADRESS IS NOT NULL THEN H.D_ADRESS
        WHEN H.F_ADRESS IS NOT NULL THEN H.F_ADRESS
        ELSE H.O_ADRESS       
     END);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would move the CASE to the Select so you get a valid value depending on the address column that has actual data. Like this:

```
DECLARE @vAdress AS VARCHAR(50)

SELECT H.FIRSTNAME, H.LASTNAME, 
@vAdress = CASE
               WHEN H.D_ADRESS IS NOT NULL THEN H.D_ADRESS
                   WHEN H.F_ADRESS IS NOT NULL THEN H.F_ADRESS
                   ELSE H.O_ADRESS       
               END, 
C.COUNTRY
FROM History H
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY C
ON H.COUNTRYCODE = C.COUNTRYCODE
WHERE H.EMAILADRESS = 'johndoe.doe@test.com'
```

In this case you will get the address value from the column that has data in it.